# How to show a loading indicator when loading the app at the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have to load many files for my AngularJs single page application, like angular.js, jquery.js, bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css, some_plugins.js, my_main.js and others,

It take some time to load the entire app, so I want to show a loading indicator (a spinner for example) in a void page until all the js and css files load and then display the content.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For Angular Apps use [Angular Loading Bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar).
Looks like [this](https://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/).

- Would apply to whenever an XHR request goes out in angular
- Can specify which request to not display loading icon
- Only displayed when the request causes user to wait
- Can be styled to your liking
- Injected into the services module and just works

Comment: I'll point out that Angular Loading Bar is good for ALL page loads, not necessarily just the first one.

Comment: This is incredibly awesome. I'd give you +100 if I could.

Comment: How can this be upvoted when it has nothing to do with the question?
Angular Loading Bar and others require Angular to be initialized/bootstrapped, but the question is about pre-bootstrap animation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14):

I've used [Pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) before on a legacy project written almost entirely in Backbone.js, in which waiting for all the dependencies to resolve was pretty painful.

It's almost no configuration to get started, so if you're looking for a relatively simple library, I'd use that one.

---

Edit:

#### From the Docs:

Include pace.js and the theme css of your choice on your page (as early as is possible), and you're done!

Pace will automatically monitor your ajax requests, event loop lag, document ready state, and elements on your page to decide the progress. On ajax navigation it will begin again!

If you use AMD or Browserify, require in pace.js and call pace.start() as early in the loading process as is possible.

Example

```
<head>
  <script src="/pace/pace.js"></script>
  <link href="/pace/themes/pace-theme-barber-shop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it in 3 steps as follows.

1.add `<div class="se-pre-con"></div>` inside `<body>`,

2.add `.se-pre-con` css class to your styles,

3.finally add these few jquery codes:

`$(window).load(function () {$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");});`

(don't forget to add JQuery library in your project)

that's it.

this is an example that work:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta content="" name="keywords">
        <meta content="" name="description">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

        <style>


            body {
                background: green;
            }

            .se-pre-con {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
                background: url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/421466/screenshots/2390664/orbit-400px.gif') center no-repeat white;
                background-size: 150px 150px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="se-pre-con"></div>

        <!--==========================
        your body content will come here
        ============================-->


        <script>
            $(window).load(function () {
                $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
            });
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

in this example because of light page the loader gif disapear very fast. but in heavy pages it is a good solution for your problem.

this is a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/jeWdIOOAtNjdjNFzEPuZ/) run

I wish it helps